# Converting xml to json in scala

Tags: json, xml, web-services, scala

In my scala project I am calling a webservice. The response from the service is XML. I want it to convert to json format. I read some articles and used Json4s library. I included it in my build.sbt file.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap"            % "3.1.1-2",
  "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-bootstrap" % "0.12.1-1",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native"        % "3.3.0"
)
```

Then I compiled the project with no errors.

When i try to import org.json4s it shows error:

```
object Json4s is not a member of package org
```

I also tried the lift json library but no use. Please help me to fix this issue. Also suggest any other solution to convert xml to json if possible. Thanks

- Play framework version - 2.3.9
- Scala - 2.11.6

Comment: did you use https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: I added spray to my sbt file. And when I import spray.json._ it show error "not found: object spray". Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: `"io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.2.5"` this the way and `libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.2.5"`

Comment: `val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(   
    resolvers += "spray" at "http://repo.spray.io/",
    libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.2.5"
)`

Comment: I think 1.2.5 is not found. I used this way libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.2"

Comment: @RajarshiDas Using spray how to convert xml to json?

Comment: now it is ready right ?  you did not get not found: object spray ?

Comment: nope. I using eclipse for editing. My friend says sometimes it may show error in eclipse. So I decided to give  a try

Comment: `import scala.xml._
import cc.spray.json._
import cc.spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

implicit object NodeFormat extends JsonFormat[Node] {
  def write(node: Node) =
    if (node.child.count(_.isInstanceOf[Text]) == 1)
      JsString(node.text)
    else
      JsObject(node.child.collect {
        case e: Elem => e.label -> write(e)
      }: _*)

  def read(jsValue: JsValue) = null // not implemented
}`

Comment: can you pls explain this a bit. Where to pass my xml and where it gets converted?

Comment: yes .`xml_data.toSeq.toJson` or `xml_data.toSeq.toJson.toString`

Comment: When i import the above it shows error while compiling. Is there a way to find whether the library is added to my project?